# Hyperopt: return boolean value instead of int

Tags: hyperopt

In the `space` param, I declare it as:

```
"langevin": hp.choice("langevin", [True, False])
```

The `fmin` successfully ran. However when I use: `model = Regressor(**best)`, it throws:  `CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/options/json_helper.h:157: Can't parse parameter "langevin" with value: 1`

How can I force the return value as True?